# "Missing closing parenthesis" MySQL error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that will show the rounded average to two decimal places. This is my code and I don't know why I keep getting the error.

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG (Scholarship, 2)) AS 'Average Scholarships'
FROM
    student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG (Scholarship), 2) AS 'Average Scholarships' FROM student;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `Scholarship, 2` to the `AVG` function, which only expects one argument.

What you meant to do was pass `AVG (Scholarship)` and `2` to `ROUND`, like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG (Scholarship), 2) AS 'Average Scholarships' FROM student;
```